# SQL server 2019 RTM Cumulative Update (CU) 12 KB5004524 (2) Last failed install attempt on 9/19/2021-0x80070643

Tags: sql-server-2019, service-pack

What causes DEV SQL 2019 to failed when patching, this is the second time it has happened and had to restore the master and backup the entire databases.

> Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'ISServer_upgrade.sql' encountered error 15151, state 1, severity 16.

Comment: Check SQL Server's error log for additional details around the failure time. It should have more in it.

Comment: The error code in the log is 0x80070643

Comment: I don't know if the author of [this article which solved it](https://www.sqlservice.se/script-level-upgrade-for-database-master-failed/) is a DBA.SE contributor, but if they don't write an answer here, you could refer to that.